# Reassigning a boolean if not true

Tags: java, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I have a method foo() and foobar() that both return a boolean. Each of them must be executed regardless of the result.

```
boolean changed = true;
while(changed) {
    changed = foo();
    if(!changed) {
        changed = foobar();
    }
    else {
        foobar();
    }
}
```

I want the loop to keep executing for as long as changed is true, but I feel like the second code block of ifs and elses for foobar() is not very... elegant. Is there a better way to write that part so that the variable changed will only be reassigned if it's not already true?

Thanks!

Comment: Ahh, @Carl Norum! You deleted your answer! It was such genius D: (assuming it works)

Comment: @Carl: didn't looked at the `changed=foo();`

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure why Carl deleted that answer.  Non-shortcircuit or is a fine solution here.

Comment: @DDP - I can put it back if you want.  @Nirmal has a better answer, though.  Mine answer is pretty subtle, and my experience is that using the clearer algorithm is always the best practice.  Someone is going to notice that `|` and think "oh - that should be a `||`", then "fix" it, and your program will stop working and no one will know why.

Comment: @DDP & @Mark Peters - answer restored for context.

Comment: @Carl Norum But bitwise operators are so pro... and elegant! D: Nirmal's solution will also be too cumbersome for additional methods that do the same thing, so yours works more than perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
changed = foo() | foobar();
```

Note the use of the bitwise or operator.

Comment: Here's what I was going to post before you deleted this ;D : Oh, genius! I knew it had to do something with that, but I never thought about using the bitwise operators that way. I'm guessing that this can be extended to more methods if needed (ie. changed = foo() | foobar() | foo1() | foo2()) and still work correctly.

Comment: @DDP yes, all those functions will get called, and if at least one of them returns `true`, `changed` will get set to `true`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's a boolean logical operator; JLS 15.22.2.  It is a bitwise operator if the operands are integer types.

Comment: @Stephen: From the JLS section you cited: *When both operands of a &, ^, or | operator are of type boolean or Boolean, then the type of the **bitwise operator** expression is boolean.*  It still calls them bitwise operators, even when it acts on booleans.

Answer (score 3):

*I want the loop to keep executing for as long as changed is true* 
 means? 
do u want to stop loop if both method returns false
if yes then do:

```
boolean changed = true;
boolean changed1 = true;

    while(changed || changed1) {
        changed = foo();
        changed1 = foobar();
    }
```

Comment: This will be bad if I add on more methods that do similar things to the loop, which is why I specifically asked for a better way to write the if..else code block. Sorry! D:

Answer (score 1):

Besides the bitwise OR option, you can also just make sure you put `changed` second in the expression and all the methods will be executed:

```
changed = foo();
changed = bar() || changed;
changed = baz() || changed;
```

I like the bitwise option better since it communicates that the methods have necessary side effects.  The above should be well documented to prevent somebody from coming along later and "fixing it to be more performant."

Comment: Oh, that's a pretty nice solution nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below shortened code styntax

```
boolean changed = true;
while(changed) {
    changed = (foo())?foobar():(true|foobar());
}
```

I edited the answer. Thanks all for pointing out the error :)

Comment: This won't execute `foobar()` if `foo()` returns `false`.

Comment: this will not work   if foo() returns false then foobar will not be executed

Comment: Opps sorry. Yes. This will not work. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: It should be as follows.
while(changed) {
  changed = (foo())? foobar():(true|foobar());
}

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want, so long as one of foo() or foobar() return true, to continue executing the loop.

```
boolean time_to_stop = false;
while (!time_to_stop) {
    boolean foo_result = foo();
    boolean foobar_result = foobar();
    if (false == (foo_result || foobar_result) ) {
        time_to_stop = true;
    }
}
```

You can shorten this by using syntactically equivalent code structures:

```
boolean keep_going = true;
while (keep_going) {
    keep_going = foo() | foobar(); 
    // bit-wise OR, avoids compiler short-circuiting optimization
}
```

To the ultimate short-hand:

```
while ( foo() | foobar() ) {};
```

Comment: If, on the other hand, the **action** of assigning true or false to the variable `changed` each time through the loop is important (perhaps due to side-effects of the underlying engine), then please note that in your original question.

Comment: `false == (foo_result || foobar_result)`.  If you ever use `==` to compare something to `true` or `false`, you're doing it wrong.  You can just use unary inversion (`!`).

Comment: Also, [Yoda conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2430307#2430307), lol.

Comment: I decided to write false== to avoid having the "hidden to the eye" `negative!` and to make it explicitly obvious what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

a nice case for using the do-while:

```
boolean changed;    // no initial value needed
do {
    changed = foo() | foobar();  // should not be ||
} while(changed);
```